Generate unique random numbers in Google Sheets
I want to generate in cells A1, B1, C1, D1, random numbers within the range 10 to 30. I have put in these cells the same function =RANDBETWEEN(10;30). However, random numbers sometimes have duplicate values, which I don't want.
So that the random numbers appearing at the same time in these 4 boxes do not overlap, what should I do?

you could add the next number to the previous number and give all numbers a range of roughly 7

There are a couple of approaches. Have a look at these for examples of a formula approach and a script approach, both on StackOverflow.

You can create like 10 random numbers, choose the first 4 unique among them:
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(UNIQUE(BYCOL(SEQUENCE(1,10),LAMBDA(r, RANDBETWEEN(10,30))),1),1,4)


This is exactly what I needed. If you know how to skillfully use functions, Excel can solve any problem. Thanks @TheMaster a lot.

This might not work correctly some time; it's rare depending on the choice of numbers, but it could happen for instance when you have a few numbers in between, and one keeps popping up too many times, so as to make the sequence shorter than needed.

Further to my comment,, the probability that the method illustrated fails is the same as randomly selecting the same n-1 number (where n=4) out of the 21 possibilities, in all of your trials (in your example 10 trials). So if you want to obtain a valid result with at least a 99% confidence C, the number of random trials will have to be [(n-1)/n]^t = 1-C. From this we obtain that t>29. If you want to be at least 99.9% confident of the result you have to go to t>44. I hope this helps understanding the flaw of the method, and vote for my method which doesn't have this flaw :-)

@gciriani Could you link some docs on how you found the formula: [(n-1)/n]^t = 1-C? Practically, for this question with the exact limits of 4 random numbers in 21, I wasn't able to get any  missing numbers(of course this was trial and error)

My apologies, but before I wrote the wrong formula out of bungled statistics. I will also make an entry in your comments to my entry (and thank for your upvote). After thinking it over, the probability that in 10 trials something goes wrong, i.e. less than 4 unique numbers, is equal to the sum of three probabilities: the probability of obtaining only 1 unique number in 10 trials; + the probability of obtaining only 2 unique numbers in 10 trials; + the probability of obtaining the only 3 unique numbers in 10 trials. It doesn't fit all in this comment; I'll append it to my solution.

You need to pick random numbers without substitution. The procedure illustrated by @TheMaster is not really picking numbers without substitution, and depending on the choice of numbers might not work correctly at times.
What you really need to guarantee that the numbers you pick are not substituted, is to generate a sequence of all the numbers from minimum to maximum,
SEQUENCE(max-min-1, 1,min)

then generate random numbers between 0 and 1,
RANDARRAY(max-min+1)

and build a matrix that has those two ranges as its columns
{sequence(max-min+1,1,min),RANDARRAY(max-min+1)}

then you sort the range from smallest to largest, according to the random numbers which are in column 2
SORT({SEQUENCE(max-min+1,1,min),RANDARRAY(max-min+1)},2,true)

Finally you obtain the sequence of n random numbers by using constraining the matrix to the first n values, and eliminating the second column which contained the uniformly distributed random ordered numbers.
ARRAY_CONSTRAIN( SORT({SEQUENCE(max-min+1,1,min),RANDARRAY(max-min+1)},2,true), n, 1)

This last formula packs all the passages above in one formula. I hope this helps.
EDIT: Statistical Appendix
The probability that in 10 trials something goes wrong with the approach suggested by TheMaster, i.e. the probability of obtaining less than 4 unique numbers, is 4.46 e-6. This is covered in this post.
I also would like to follow up on a false equivalence written in a comment: that RANDARRAY is also not guaranteed to not repeat the same number. I tested that hypothesis with a RANDARRAY of 10 million numbers (that's the maximum size Google Sheets allows me to enter), and there wasn't one single repeat. One can test it with the formula
LET(N, 1000, COUNTUNIQUE(RANDARRAY(N)) - N), for 1000 unique numbers

which will give zero, even with N up to 10,000,000, because the unique numbers in the RANDARRAY of N numbers are exactly N.
Keep in mind that Google Sheets generates numbers with 15 significant digits, and the random number generator is probably using an elliptic function; therefore if Google allowed it in its memory banks, we could have gone theoretically even higher, around 1000 trillion before repeating a random number.

Good. While the chances are low, RANDARRAY isn't guaranteed to not give any duplicates. So, I wonder about the chances of picking the numbers next to each other or the actual randomness(Within the constraints of the question, this shouldn't matter though)

For new users, to apply the formula to the question, it would look  like =LET(min,10, max,30,n,4, ARRAY_CONSTRAIN( SORT({SEQUENCE(max-min+1,1,min),RANDARRAY(max-min+1)},2,1), n, 1) )

An alternative that uses the random number generator less often would be to sample 4 uniform numbers and transform those to the desired range using the quantile function (which is conditional on the previous numbers).
A2 = RANDBETWEEN(0;20)
B2 = RANDBETWEEN(0;19)
C2 = RANDBETWEEN(0;18)
D2 = RANDBETWEEN(0;17)

you shift some of those numbers by one based on conditional statements.
A3 = A2
B3 = IF((B2+1>A3), B2 + 1, B2)
C3 = IFS(SUM(1*(C2+2>A3),1*(C2+2>B3)) = 2,
           C2+2,
         SUM(1*(C2+1>A3),1*(C2+1>B3)) = 1, 
           C2+1,
         TRUE(), 
           C2             
        )
D3 = IFS(SUM(1*(D2+3>A3),1*(D2+3>B3),1*(D2+3>C3)) = 3, 
           D2+3,
         SUM(1*(D2+2>A3),1*(D2+2>B3),1*(D2+2>C3)) = 2, 
           D2+2,     
         SUM(1*(D2+1>A3),1*(D2+1>B3),1*(D2+1>C3)) = 1, 
           D2+1,
         TRUE(), 
           D2
        )

And finally add 10
A1 = A3+10
B1 = B3+10
C1 = C3+10 
D1 = D3+10 

